# The "trick" functions in the "$\pi$ is transcendental" proofs

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi, transcendental-numbers

I was reading [this paper](http://sixthform.info/maths/files/pitrans.pdf) and I wondered how did Hermite decide to define a function $$f(x)=\frac{x^{p-1}(x-1)^p\cdots (x-m)^p}{(p-1)!}$$

Are these functions only tricks or there is a deeper meaning?

Comment: Did you read the proof and tried to think about how those polinomials were used?

Comment: I understand the proof and the only thing I see is that the proof is correct, but not why this function is defined like this. Is there any motivation?

Comment: @dotdot I sympathize.  It's rare for mathematical writing to be written in the order of discovery, but rather in the order that involves the least amount of writing and appears the most magical.  Thus, there are lots of analysis proofs that start with "Let $\epsilon$ be less than ( insert bizarre looking function here )".  If you start from the bottom of those proofs and keep track of the properties of $\epsilon$ that you need, you can usually reconstruct the function yourself and it seems quite natural.  Pretty much the same things applies here.

Comment: A related article is [_Discovering and Proving that $\pi$ Is Irrational_](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/000298910x492853) by Timothy W. Jones. Ivan Niven's proof of the irrationality of $\pi$ is motivated.